# JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject (Project Eclipse To Android Studio)

Tags: android, json

after i import the project and fix some problem i got the json error like the title i mention, can you help me please. In the IDE nothing with error sign (red sign)

[ImageProblemHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKUY1.jpg)

if you need anything else just ask below

Here is my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (Result != null) {
            parseJson(Result); // here problem
        } else {
            // intent_depan();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx,
                    "Login Failed, Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }


    // Android monitor show the problem maybe here
    public void parseJson(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
            String stat = jobj.getString("stat");

            // Log.i("json result", "string result " + s1);
            if (stat.equals("failed")) {
                String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                userName = jobj.getString("name");
                // Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, userName,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                saveLoginState();

                goToMainActivity();
            }

            /*
             * if (s1 == "success") { intent_depan(); } else {
             * intent_depan(); }
             */
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First: Please post your error as text in the issue, rather than sharing a screenshot. Second: The response you get is '<h1>404' which isn't valid JSON off course

Comment: The URL you are calling is wrong

Comment: Is that even the code that resulted in that error? I can't really see a line where it tries to parse the invalid JSON.

Comment: in the `parseJson(String s)` method..You should create your `JSONObject`  as `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);`

Comment: Your question is not about Android Studio, so please don't tag it. It also isn't the problem because making the same network request from running the code in Eclipse would get the exact same HTTP error response and throw the exact same error. So, the problem is either the API or how you access it

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Sorry just check again this thread..text error just like on my screenshot, i dont know where is the error exactly

Comment: @PasiMatalamäki yeah,, just like that,, and make me confused, I dont know the problem on the code here or on the server i try to connect with.

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm sorry before cause i build it on the android studio i think is related,, but sorry if not,, i dont know

Comment: You are trying to parse HTML as JSON, which simply isn't possible. Your code is fine, but obviously missing proper error handling. The server, on the other hand is not okay and Codo's answer is correct

Comment: @cricket_007 I try to change the url and i got username and password is invalid, it means the url dont have database login like i input ? or any other problem with my code ? before i check on the rest url, the user and pass are true.. but on the apps is invalid

Comment: If you get a response like that, then yes, that makes sense... I don't know what you're trying to ask. Your error question only shows you parsing JSON, you are welcome to [edit] to rephrase the problem and include the full code as a [mcve]

Comment: sorry i'm forget about the main topic is all about json parse error why ? but i think on the url and the server side.. thanks for help me analys all of this, and another problem gonna post on the next question. sorry for my poor knowledge.. once again thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server's response cannot cannot be parsed as JSON because the server returns an error message (in HTML) instead of JSON data.

It's a *HTTP 404 Not found* error, indicating that the URL was probably invalid.

It would also be good practice to check if the HTTP request was successful at all. If it wasn't, don't even try to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: I try to change the url and i got username and password is invalid, it means the url dont have database login like i input ? or any other problem with my code ? before i check on the rest url, the user and pass are true.. but on the apps is invalid

Comment: This is difficult to tell without further information. It depends on the specific web app / service, which URLs require authentication and which don't. And there can be a variety of different authentication scheme, e.g. using a cookies, specifying username/password in each request or some sort of token in the request header. If you're stuck with authentication, start a new question and provide all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

creat a json object from result like this and before parsing also check the result string is a valid json string or not.

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
```

Comment: This will throw a JSON parse exception on its own. No need to check the string